# Sitecore Form Module Security Editor

Tags: sitecore-forms, role-management, editor-user-permissions

In the `sitecore\Forms Editor` role access is provided as below:

[image]

This security works fine in `Content Editor`, that is:

It allows to create or edit items only in the English language but not in other languages. But the behavior is not the same in the Forms module. In the Forms module from launchpad, forms can be created in other languages irrespective of the security provided in roles.
How do I restrict form creation in other languages in `Forms Module`?

Answer (score 0):

To do this we need to manage `All form` or `Form Designer` Item (form module) from core db.

Tried to revoke create, edit access for form editor Role from core db
`/sitecore/client/Applications/FormsBuilder/Pages/Forms` after selecting another language but it getting to applied to all language.

I would suggest to manage language permission on user level not Form Editor role level (You can also create custom role and on the apply permission).

Another approach: once form open on form designer, you can disable language click which not wanted to selectable from Language dropdown.

Comment: Even in user level also , if read access is provided for multiple language, then in Form module the forms can be created in all languages. But in Content Editor that is not the case.

Comment: yes, same I am also getting same behavior.
what if you give particular language access to user level, but in this case that user will able to work for every item on particular language.
As per your screenshot.